# Printing out in unformated output c++

Tags: c++, io, output

I am in the process of creating a Huffman Tree and I want to print out the frequency of each letter in unformated output. However, my issue is that I am unable to print anything. This is my process:

```
char c;
unsigned int freqArray[256];
unsigned int valueShifted[256];

while (!cin.eof())
{
  c = cin.get();
  freqArray[(int)c]++;
} //mapping my frequency array to the letter it sees


void shifting(unsigned int *freqArray, unsigned int *valueShifted)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    if(freqArray[i] > 0)
    {
      valueShifted[i] = (freqArray[i] << 24) | ((freqArray[i] << 8) & 0x00ff0000) | ((freqArray[i] >> 8) & 0x0000ff00) | (freqArray[i] >> 24); // shifting of bits
    }
  }


  shifting(freqArray, valueShifted);
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    if(valueShifted[i] > 0)
    {
      cout.write((char*)&valueShifted[i], sizeof(valueShifted[i])); //this is not printing anything
    }
  }
```

Might anyone know why this isn't printing anything? I'm guessing my error may be because I am not printing out in HEX but I'm not entirely sure... if anyone could help that'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't quite make sense... But it should write something to console though, you might just not see it (i.e. unprintable characters and/or no flushing is happening).

Comment: you are missing cout.flush();

Answer (score 3):

You want to output each `unsigned int` in the array?

```
cout << valueShifted[i];
```

The `write` is a low-level write. With your example, you'd need to use a binary editor to see the values you are writing. Depending on your terminal and on the content of the data, dumping binary data to stdout could result in garbage printed, or nothing.